# keeping TFS vnext builds under version control

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Can I keep my vnext builds under version control? I'm editing them only via the TFS "Build" tab and I'd like to use git type tools to track changes, revert etc. Am I missing something? are these builds available for edit via VisualStudio like the xaml ones were somewhere? is there a tool that all the cool kids are using that I don't know about?

Comment: You don't have to. Do your build don't have a history tab? Use it to see changes.

Comment: My pipelines are getting quite large and the history tab isn't working for me as well as git log would.

Comment: @RodrigoWerlang That's not exactly true. Versioning build/release definitions as source code alongside the application is a very good practice. Builds and releases evolve alongside your application, and source code should be the single version of truth for all things related to your application. If a build breaks, I don't want to have to look in multiple places to figure out why. I want to look at the last commit and see what changed that broke the build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can opt-in to [YAML build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/build-yaml?view=vsts) in order to enable version controlling build definitions.